# Data is not reaching to the websocket clients in AWS API Gateway websocket

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I have created an lambda function to which I am not able to send the data to the web socket clients. However there is NO error is coming.

Till yesterday code was working. Dont know what happend now it stopped working.

```cs
    public string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                string SK = "xxxxxx";
                string AK = "xxxx";
    
                var stream = new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
                
                var apiClient = new AmazonApiGatewayManagementApiClient(AK,SK,new AmazonApiGatewayManagementApiConfig 
                { ServiceURL = $"https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Test" });
                
                apiClient.PostToConnectionAsync(new Amazon.ApiGatewayManagementApi.Model.PostToConnectionRequest
                {
                    ConnectionId = "​fdCqPfd0oAMCJmg=",
                    Data = stream
                });
    
                return input.ToUpper();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I gather you're using .NET [`AmazonApiGatewayManagementApiClient`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/ApiGatewayManagementApi/TApiGatewayManagementApiClient.html). You're missing the `await` keyword for `apiClient.PostToConnectionAsync()`:

```cs
await apiClient.PostToConnectionAsync(...);
```

Otherwise you're calling `PostToConnectionAsync()` without waiting for completion and your Lambda might complete and exit *before* your request is run and you'll never know about it. (See [asynchronous concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) for details)

Alternatively, don't use async method:

```cs
apiClient.PostToConnection(...);
```